# Booting Ubuntu Studio sticks at different points (HP Pavilion Desktop PC)

Tags: boot, system-installation

I am trying to boot into Ubuntu Studio 20.4.3. I downloaded the Live ISO and put it onto a 32 GB EMTEC USB Stick with Rufus (GPT/UEFI) under Windows. I also checked the ISO File hashsum.

I have a HP Pavilion Desktop PC TP01-2xxx and I want to install Ubuntu Studio (when booting works) on the 512 GB PCIe NVMe M.2 SSD.

So I boot from the stick and select "Try Ubuntu w/o Installing" - and here I also deleted "quiet" and "splash" and get this info:

Begin ... casper-premount ... done
done
stdin: Invalid argument

My screen looks like this:
https://herrvoelker.de/tmp/photo_2021-11-09_17-40-41.jpg

Edit 1: When I use the MBR/BIOS partition scheme in Rufus, I get a more complex error, which really looks frightening:
https://herrvoelker.de/tmp/photo_2021-11-09_18-13-09.jpg

Edit 2: As Windows is still running on the 512 GB PCIe NVMe M.2 SSD - I think I can rule out that this is a hardware issue.

Edit 3: I used another USB Stick (SanDisk 16GB) and it seems to boot a bit further, but still sticks at some point:

https://herrvoelker.de/tmp/photo_2021-11-09_20-10-26.jpg

Edit 4: When I then boot a second time from the new stick, it sticks again at the original point. So I can't even reproduce the same errors.

Lately the error message looked like this:

https://herrvoelker.de/tmp/photo_2021-11-09_20-22-15.jpg

Edit 5: The USB port that I use seems to have an effect too.

Any ideas?

Comment: The first thing you should try is to use a different USB-stick.

Comment: @mook765: Thanks for the suggestion regarding another USB-stick. The boot process seems to go a bit further now (see Edit 3), but still does not complete.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to boot into Ubuntu Studio - booting with "acpi=off" and "nomodeset" (and w/o quiet and splash of course).

Edit: to do "nomodeset" is not necessary, it will still boot, so the "acpi=off" is the important thing to do = turning off the power management functions of the computer.

Ubuntu also detects my 512 GB PCIe NVMe M.2 SSD, where I will now install Ubuntu Studio to. Hopefully the system will boot from SSD then - of course without "acpi=off".