# Grub Bootloader installation error on NVMe SSD or SATA HD (HP Pavilion Desktop PC)

Tags: grub2, system-installation, grub-efi, nvme

After managing to boot into an Ubuntu Studio Live system on USB by using acpi=off ...

[Booting Ubuntu Studio sticks at different points (HP Pavilion Desktop PC)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1374545/booting-ubuntu-studio-sticks-at-different-points-hp-pavilion-desktop-pc) ...

I can't install the bootloader grub to the NVMe.

The installation procedure seems to have no problems generating the partitions automatically (one for EFI, one for /) - but then returns with Errorcode 1:

grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-id=ubuntu --force

http://herrvoelker.de/tmp/photo_2021-11-10_11-55-43.jpg

Edit 1: I then tried to install Ubuntu+Bootloader to the SATA HD, but again get this error message. So it's a more general problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Ubuntu's Ubiquity only wants to install to an ESP on first drive. UEFI/BIOS defines what is first drive. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO (unless 21.10)
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  See similar? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1374597/trying-to-reinstall-ubuntu-on-an-external-nvme-drive-but-getting-error-when-boot

Comment: @oldfred Thanks for the comment. Before I read your comment regarding ESP only on the first drive (which I defined as the USB ports in UEFI/BIOS), I found this boot-repair tool and let the auto fix run. Interestingly it gave out an error message (An error occurred during the repair), but still the booting does now work. I am not sure why: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/tChZMR2pd7/

Comment: Boot-Repair often flags errors with trying to do something on installer flash drive which is not really an error. But the cannot write grub entry (line 59) does not seem correct. But you still show UEFI boot entries and they usually do not change unless you reformat partitions which changes GUID & UUID. Check if your system has some way to lock UEFI from changes, some seem to have that setting.